# True or false: if $S_n\sim B(n,p),$ then...

Tags: probability

I have to prove if the next statement is true or false:

If $S_n \sim B(n,p),$ then for every $t$ and $n$:
$$
\left| P\left( \frac{S_n - np}{\sqrt{np(1-p)}} >t \right) - P(Z>t) \right| < \frac 1 {2\sqrt{np(1-p)}},
$$

where $Z\sim N(0,1).$

First, I use Moivre–Laplace Theorem to show that the fraction converges in distribution to $Z,$ and then I use characteristic functions, but I don´t know how to decide if it is true or not.
Can you help me?

Comment: Seems a special case of the Berry–Esseen theorem

Comment: See if the explicit bound in https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Berry-Esseen_inequality helps.